# Errors when deploying Simulink model to Arduino Due

Tags: arduino-due

I am trying to connect an Arduino Due to Simulink to run it in external mode. I am unable to successfully deploy to hardware.

I'm testing it with a blinking light model: A pulse generator connected to a digital output pin. This is the error message:

```
  ### Starting build procedure for model: due_blink
   Code Generation  1
  Elapsed: 8 sec
  ### Generating code into build folder: C:\Users\Dana\Documents\MATLAB\due_blink_ert_rtw
  ### Invoking Target Language Compiler on due_blink.rtw
  ### Using System Target File: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\rtw\c\ert\ert.tlc
  ### Loading TLC function libraries
  ### Initial pass through model to cache user defined code
  ### Caching model source code
  ### Writing header file due_blink.h
  ### Writing header file due_blink_types.h
  .
  ### Writing header file rtwtypes.h
  ### Writing source file due_blink.c
  ### Writing header file due_blink_private.h
  ### Writing source file due_blink_data.c
  ### Writing header file rtmodel.h
  .
  ### Writing source file ert_main.c
  ### TLC code generation complete.
  ### Evaluating PostCodeGenCommand specified in the model
  ### Using toolchain: Arduino ARM v1.6.1 | gmake (64-bit Windows)
  ### 'C:\Users\Dana\Documents\MATLAB\due_blink_ert_rtw\due_blink.mk' is up to date
  ### Building 'due_blink': C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2015b\bin\win64\gmake -f due_blink.mk all
  C:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino-1.6.1/hardware/tools/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4.8.3-2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -Os -c -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -nostdlib --param max-inline-insns-single=500 -Dprintf=iprintf -DARDUINO=161  -MD -mcpu=cortex-m3 -DF_CPU=84000000L -DARDUINO_SAM_DUE -DARDUINO_ARCH_SAM -D__SAM3X8E__ -mthumb -DUSB_VID=0x2341 -DUSB_PID=0x003e -DUSBCON -DUSB_MANUFACTURER='"Unknown"' -DUSB_PRODUCT='"Arduino Due"' -D_RUNONTARGETHARDWARE_BUILD_ -D_ROTH_DUE_ -DMODEL=due_blink -DNUMST=1 -DNCSTATES=0 -DHAVESTDIO -DONESTEPFCN=1 -DTERMFCN=1 -DMAT_FILE=0 -DMULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 -DINTEGER_CODE=0 -DMT=0 -DCLASSIC_INTERFACE=0 -DALLOCATIONFCN=0 -DTID01EQ=0 -D__MW_TARGET_USE_HARDWARE_RESOURCES_H__ -DEXIT_FAILURE=1 -DEXTMODE_DISABLEPRINTF -DEXTMODE_DISABLETESTING -DEXTMODE_DISABLE_ARGS_PROCESSING=1 -DRT -DSTACK_SIZE=64 -DMW_TIMERID=9 -DMW_TIMERCOUNT=131250 -DMW_SAM_CLOCKID=TC_CMR_TCCLKS_TIMER_CLOCK3 -D_RTT_BAUDRATE_SERIAL0_=9600 -D_RTT_BAUDRATE_SERIAL1_=9600 -D_RTT_BAUDRATE_SERIAL2_=9600 -D_RTT_BAUDRATE_SERIAL3_=9600 -D_RTT_ANALOG_REF_=0 -DONESTEPFCN=1 -DTERMFCN=1 -DMAT_FILE=0 -DMULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 -DINTEGER_CODE=0 -DMT=0 -DCLASSIC_INTERFACE=0 -DALLOCATIONFCN=0 -DTID01EQ=0 -DEXIT_FAILURE=1 -DEXTMODE_DISABLEPRINTF -DEXTMODE_DISABLETESTING -DEXTMODE_DISABLE_ARGS_PROCESSING=1 -DRT -DSTACK_SIZE=64 -DMODEL=due_blink -DNUMST=1 -DNCSTATES=0 -DHAVESTDIO -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduinobase/toolbox/target/supportpackages/arduinobase/include -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduinobase/toolbox/target/supportpackages/arduinobase/blocks/sfcn/include -IC:/Users/Dana/Documents/MATLAB/due_blink_ert_rtw -IC:/Users/Dana/Documents/MATLAB -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015b/extern/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015b/simulink/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015b/rtw/c/src -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015b/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015b/rtw/c/ert -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino-1.6.1/hardware/arduino/sam/system/libsam -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino-1.6.1/hardware/arduino/sam/system/CMSIS/CMSIS/Include -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino-1.6.1/hardware/arduino/sam/system/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino-1.6.1/hardware/arduino/sam/cores/arduino -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino-1.6.1/hardware/arduino/sam/variants/arduino_due_x -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino/toolbox/target/supportpackages/arduinotarget/registry/../include -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino/toolbox/target/supportpackages/arduinotarget/registry/../scheduler/include -o "due_blink.o" "due_blink.c" 
  C:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino-1.6.1/hardware/tools/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4.8.3-2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -Os -c -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -nostdlib --param max-inline-insns-single=500 -Dprintf=iprintf -DARDUINO=161  -MD -mcpu=cortex-m3 -DF_CPU=84000000L -DARDUINO_SAM_DUE -DARDUINO_ARCH_SAM -D__SAM3X8E__ -mthumb -DUSB_VID=0x2341 -DUSB_PID=0x003e -DUSBCON -DUSB_MANUFACTURER='"Unknown"' -DUSB_PRODUCT='"Arduino Due"' -D_RUNONTARGETHARDWARE_BUILD_ -D_ROTH_DUE_ -DMODEL=due_blink -DNUMST=1 -DNCSTATES=0 -DHAVESTDIO -DONESTEPFCN=1 -DTERMFCN=1 -DMAT_FILE=0 -DMULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 -DINTEGER_CODE=0 -DMT=0 -DCLASSIC_INTERFACE=0 -DALLOCATIONFCN=0 -DTID01EQ=0 -D__MW_TARGET_USE_HARDWARE_RESOURCES_H__ -DEXIT_FAILURE=1 -DEXTMODE_DISABLEPRINTF -DEXTMODE_DISABLETESTING -DEXTMODE_DISABLE_ARGS_PROCESSING=1 -DRT -DSTACK_SIZE=64 -DMW_TIMERID=9 -DMW_TIMERCOUNT=131250 -DMW_SAM_CLOCKID=TC_CMR_TCCLKS_TIMER_CLOCK3 -D_RTT_BAUDRATE_SERIAL0_=9600 -D_RTT_BAUDRATE_SERIAL1_=9600 -D_RTT_BAUDRATE_SERIAL2_=9600 -D_RTT_BAUDRATE_SERIAL3_=9600 -D_RTT_ANALOG_REF_=0 -DONESTEPFCN=1 -DTERMFCN=1 -DMAT_FILE=0 -DMULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 -DINTEGER_CODE=0 -DMT=0 -DCLASSIC_INTERFACE=0 -DALLOCATIONFCN=0 -DTID01EQ=0 -DEXIT_FAILURE=1 -DEXTMODE_DISABLEPRINTF -DEXTMODE_DISABLETESTING -DEXTMODE_DISABLE_ARGS_PROCESSING=1 -DRT -DSTACK_SIZE=64 -DMODEL=due_blink -DNUMST=1 -DNCSTATES=0 -DHAVESTDIO -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduinobase/toolbox/target/supportpackages/arduinobase/include -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduinobase/toolbox/target/supportpackages/arduinobase/blocks/sfcn/include -IC:/Users/Dana/Documents/MATLAB/due_blink_ert_rtw -IC:/Users/Dana/Documents/MATLAB -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015b/extern/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015b/simulink/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015b/rtw/c/src -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015b/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015b/rtw/c/ert -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino-1.6.1/hardware/arduino/sam/system/libsam -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino-1.6.1/hardware/arduino/sam/system/CMSIS/CMSIS/Include -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino-1.6.1/hardware/arduino/sam/system/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino-1.6.1/hardware/arduino/sam/cores/arduino -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino-1.6.1/hardware/arduino/sam/variants/arduino_due_x -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino/toolbox/target/supportpackages/arduinotarget/registry/../include -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino/toolbox/target/supportpackages/arduinotarget/registry/../scheduler/include -o "due_blink_data.o" "due_blink_data.c"
  C:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino-1.6.1/hardware/tools/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4.8.3-2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -Os -c -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -nostdlib --param max-inline-insns-single=500 -Dprintf=iprintf -DARDUINO=161  -MD -mcpu=cortex-m3 -DF_CPU=84000000L -DARDUINO_SAM_DUE -DARDUINO_ARCH_SAM -D__SAM3X8E__ -mthumb -DUSB_VID=0x2341 -DUSB_PID=0x003e -DUSBCON -DUSB_MANUFACTURER='"Unknown"' -DUSB_PRODUCT='"Arduino Due"' -D_RUNONTARGETHARDWARE_BUILD_ -D_ROTH_DUE_ -DMODEL=due_blink -DNUMST=1 -DNCSTATES=0 -DHAVESTDIO -DONESTEPFCN=1 -DTERMFCN=1 -DMAT_FILE=0 -DMULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 -DINTEGER_CODE=0 -DMT=0 -DCLASSIC_INTERFACE=0 -DALLOCATIONFCN=0 -DTID01EQ=0 -D__MW_TARGET_USE_HARDWARE_RESOURCES_H__ -DEXIT_FAILURE=1 -DEXTMODE_DISABLEPRINTF -DEXTMODE_DISABLETESTING -DEXTMODE_DISABLE_ARGS_PROCESSING=1 -DRT -DSTACK_SIZE=64 -DMW_TIMERID=9 -DMW_TIMERCOUNT=131250 -DMW_SAM_CLOCKID=TC_CMR_TCCLKS_TIMER_CLOCK3 -D_RTT_BAUDRATE_SERIAL0_=9600 -D_RTT_BAUDRATE_SERIAL1_=9600 -D_RTT_BAUDRATE_SERIAL2_=9600 -D_RTT_BAUDRATE_SERIAL3_=9600 -D_RTT_ANALOG_REF_=0 -DONESTEPFCN=1 -DTERMFCN=1 -DMAT_FILE=0 -DMULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 -DINTEGER_CODE=0 -DMT=0 -DCLASSIC_INTERFACE=0 -DALLOCATIONFCN=0 -DTID01EQ=0 -DEXIT_FAILURE=1 -DEXTMODE_DISABLEPRINTF -DEXTMODE_DISABLETESTING -DEXTMODE_DISABLE_ARGS_PROCESSING=1 -DRT -DSTACK_SIZE=64 -DMODEL=due_blink -DNUMST=1 -DNCSTATES=0 -DHAVESTDIO -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduinobase/toolbox/target/supportpackages/arduinobase/include -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduinobase/toolbox/target/supportpackages/arduinobase/blocks/sfcn/include -IC:/Users/Dana/Documents/MATLAB/due_blink_ert_rtw -IC:/Users/Dana/Documents/MATLAB -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015b/extern/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015b/simulink/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015b/rtw/c/src -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015b/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015b/rtw/c/ert -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino-1.6.1/hardware/arduino/sam/system/libsam -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino-1.6.1/hardware/arduino/sam/system/CMSIS/CMSIS/Include -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino-1.6.1/hardware/arduino/sam/system/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino-1.6.1/hardware/arduino/sam/cores/arduino -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino-1.6.1/hardware/arduino/sam/variants/arduino_due_x -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino/toolbox/target/supportpackages/arduinotarget/registry/../include -IC:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino/toolbox/target/supportpackages/arduinotarget/registry/../scheduler/include -o "USBCore.o" "C:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino-1.6.1/hardware/arduino/sam/cores/arduino/USB/USBCore.cpp"
  <command-line>:0:13: error: initializer fails to determine size of 'STRING_PRODUCT' 
  C:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino-1.6.1/hardware/arduino/sam/cores/arduino/USB/USBCore.cpp:69:34: note: in expansion of macro 'USB_PRODUCT' 
   const uint8_t STRING_PRODUCT[] = USB_PRODUCT; 
                                    ^ 
  <command-line>:0:13: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer 
  C:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/arduino-1.6.1/hardware/arduino/sam/cores/arduino/USB/USBCore.cpp:69:34: note: in expansion of macro 'USB_PRODUCT' 
   const uint8_t STRING_PRODUCT[] = USB_PRODUCT; 
                                    ^ 
  gmake: *** [USBCore.o] Error 1
  ### Build procedure for model: 'due_blink' aborted due to an error.
  Error(s) encountered while building "due_blink":
  ### Failed to generate all binary outputs.
  Component: Simulink | Category: Model error
```

I have the Arduino Due board selected in the settings, with the correct COM port. When running the same model with an Arduino Uno, ld.exe crashes with exit status 255.

I can connect to the board in the Matlab command window and manually change the pins to HIGH or LOW, so it must be a problem with Simulink.

Any help would be appreciated.